# React Bootstrap using Nav component refreshes the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I tried using simple Link with bootstrap class as shown below and it worked fine.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <Link class="nav-link" to="/">
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <Link class="nav-link" to="/login">
            Login
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <Link class="nav-link" to="/product">
            Product
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <Link class="nav-link" to="/product/3">
            Details
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

But when I tried to use the `Nav` component from the `react-bootstrap` library as shown below, it refreshes the app on each click like using an anchor tag, that might be because I am using `href` here. But I don't know how can I just use a property similar to `to` in `Link`.

```
<Nav defaultActiveKey="/" as="ul">
      <Nav.Item as="li">
        <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item as="li">
        <Nav.Link href="/login">Login</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item as="li">
        <Nav.Link href="/product">Product</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
</Nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Nav.Link` with `as={Link}`, `to` instead of `href` props like below:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/login">...</Nav.Link>
```

Working example [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-nav-active-link-eqm0f)